# How to se pseudo elements outside a li

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have an `ul` with several `li` elements, I use `display: inline-block` to align them horizontal. When I want a individual `li` on a new line and use `li::before {content: "\a"; white-space: pre;}` the line-break is placed inside the `li`. Is it possible to get the line-break before the `li` element?

Comment: Try `::marker` instead of `::before`. Also, if you change `display` on `<li>` it is no longer `list-item`. It might be best just to add `display: flex` on `<ul>`

Comment: This has the same effect.

Comment: But the problem is indeed with the display: inline-block. I'll try other options.